# How to do inverse Fourier transformation with Seismic Unix?

Tags: software, seismic

I convert data from $t$-$x$ domain to $f$-$k$ domain to do dip filter using `sudipfilt` command. After that it should return to the $t$-$x$ domain. Which command should it be?

Comment: While your question is technically on-topic here, I doubt that anyone here is familiar with Seismic Unix. It's a highly specialized software. Since you're coming from [earthscience.se], I wonder if it wouldn't be a better place for this question. Do they accept questions about software?

Comment: The following link indicates that the the T-X to F-K and inverse transform are done within sudipfilt: http://www.geo.mtu.edu/~ctyoung/Robinson/filterfk.htm

Comment: Than you the problem solved